# Windows command-line utility for interruptable download

Tags: windows, command-line, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Persistent retrying resuming downloads with curl](https://superuser.com/questions/142459/persistent-retrying-resuming-downloads-with-curl)
>   [resume a file using curl or wget?](https://superuser.com/questions/240198/resume-a-file-using-curl-or-wget)

I'm looking for a Windows command-line utility similar to `curl`, but that doesn't trash the download if the internet connection gets temporarily disconnected.

If it's possible to make `curl` behave like this, that would be great too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persistent retrying resuming downloads with curl](http://superuser.com/questions/142459/persistent-retrying-resuming-downloads-with-curl) also see: [resume a file using curl or wget?](http://superuser.com/questions/240198/resume-a-file-using-curl-or-wget)

Answer (score 2):

I use `wget` for such downloads under both Windows and Linux which has an optional argument (-c) that resumes the download of a partially downloaded file.

A Windows port of wget can be found [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).